# Find the cell with more common subcells

Tags: vba, excel

I haven't seen any similar question to this one. Thank you in advance for your help!

I have these two columns:
Final Product - Subcomponent
A - 1
B - 1
C - 1
D - 1
A - 2
C - 2
B - 3
C - 3
A - 4
C - 4
D - 4
A - 5
B - 5

Final product A is made with the subcomponents 1, 2,4 and 5.
B is made with the subcomponents 1,3 and 5.
C is made with the subcomponents 1,2 and 4.
D is made with the subcomponents 1 and 4.
What I am looking for is an algorithm in vba or pivot tables that optimizes the final production in this way:
1 repeats 4 times.
2 repeats 2 times.
3 repeats 2 times.
4 repeats 3 times.
5 repeats 2 times.

First A should be made because it has more common components. Then B should be made because there is just 1 component missing compared with A. Then C because there is just one component to be replaced and last D because there is has the same two components as C.
I know this is not easy at all... Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried until now? Anyways, as you said, PivotTables can help you. Just extract to 1 column the Final Product Part and other column should be the Subcomponent Part and then you can organise your data with SumIf or CountIf or even PivotTables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim d       As Object
    Dim v       As Variant
    Dim m       As Long
    Dim r       As Long
    Dim i       As Long

    m = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Range("A1:B" & m).Value
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For r = 1 To m
        If d.Exists(v(r, 1)) Then
            d(v(r, 1)) = d(v(r, 1)) & ", " & v(r, 2)
        Else
            d(v(r, 1)) = v(r, 2)
        End If
    Next r

    Range("E1").Resize(d.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(d.Keys)
    Range("F1").Resize(d.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(d.Items)
End Sub
```